# Random flickering in Preview when viewing PDF files

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, pdf, preview

I'm running the latest MBP 15" with the built-in Intel HD Graphics 530 and the AMD Radeon Pro 460 with automatic switching.
When viewing PDF files in Preview (it happens with all of them, all kinds of sizes) after some time (10-30 seconds), I start to get flickering. It's merely the PDF content, tough, that's flickering, not the entire screen.
Could the problem be associated with all the notes that I have in some of the PDF documents? (Like textboxes, lines, arrows, etc.).
I couldn't find any help on this elsewhere, hence I'm asking here.
Thanks!

Comment: It is well possible that you see the refreshing of the view, and it is known that comments do take some time to render. You may with that get a timing effect, that you see intermediate views when refreshing the view.

Comment: It is happening to me too since the 10.12.3 update. Even without annotation, it happens on all PDFs with selectable text. To reproduce it, simply select a random word by double-clicking it.

Comment: +1 for me. Definitely happening to me too. Reproducible on clicking any word, but it also just occurs on its own every few minutes. Someone should let Apple know.

Comment: MacBook Pro 2015, macOS 10.12.3, PREVIEW Version 9.0 (909.12), same issues. https://redd.it/5oa8x7

Comment: I am also running the most recent MBP 15" but I also find the problem on a 2013 MBP 13". It seems to stop for a while if I close Preview and re-open it.